# What is a real life analogy of busy waiting by process "i" when "turn=i"?

Tags: operating-systems, synchronization

```
#define N 2
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int flag[N]={FALSE}
int turn;
void process(int i)
{
    int j=NOT(i);
    while(1)

    {
        a) NON-Critical Section();
        b) flag[i]=TRUE;
        c) turn=i;
        d) while(flag[j]==TRUE && turn==i)
        {
            //wait
        }
        e) Critical section
        f) flag[i]=FALSE;
    }
}
```

While I can trace the solution and verify it works, what's confusing is probably the name of variables or the way they're used.

when turn==i , why should process"i" wait?
That just sound ridiculous to me.

Can you give a real life analogy to this? If turn==i then i should enter the critical section is what I think logically because it's his turn.

Maybe it's the variable name?

Comment: It just means that $i$ is waiting its turn… I don't really see any question about computer science in your post.

Answer (score 0):

[Alternative representations](https://shop.elsevier.com/books/the-art-of-multiprocessor-programming/herlihy/978-0-12-415950-1)  of this algorithm use variables `victim` rather then `turn` and `level` rather than `flag`.
This algorithm ensures mutual exclusion because it employs the Peterson's principles inductively, that is, there is a competition on some level $j$ and at most one process is stopped from accessing the level $j+1$. Applying this idea for each competition enforces at most one process will enter CS.
Consequently, the idea is that the `victim` process at level $j$ is forced to wait and loses the chance to enter the next competition on level $j+1$.
CS corresponds to the competition at the topmost level.